# Mule ESB LDAP fetch all groups in tree

Tags: ldap, mule, esb

I'm able to fetch users from our AD service, but I have to select per OU group (every group/sub tree is another customer). How do I fetch the whole tree including the users?

If not possible in one step, how do I find which OU-groups are available?

Thanks, Arnoud

Comment: Can you add more details , like the structure of DIT and what you are trying to achieve ? An example explaining what you have tried so far should help. Also what do you mean by an OU-Group ?

Answer (score 0):

Our Windows AD server is built up like a tree:

LAN

--domain

----productname1.

------customername1

--------account1

--------account2

------customername2

--------account3

--------account4

----productname2

When I want to retrieve all the accounts for customername1, I have to fully specify the tree-location of the account:
OU=customername1,OU=productname1,DC=domain,DC=LAN

When I try to retrieve the accounts with an OpenQuery I receive this AD path:
LDAP://servername/CN=account1,OU=customername1,OU=productname1,DC=domain,DC=LAN

How do I get a list of the customername1 ?